# Xceed extended WPF datagrid select row with right click

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, selecteditem, right-click, xceed-datagrid

I am trying to add a context menu to an Xceed extended WPF datagrid. I am able to show the context menu and the commands fire from the menu, but right clicking on a row does not set it as the selected row and so the wrong record is used by the command.

Is there a way to change the way the selected item is set so that it can be updated by right click?

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecordsForList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Header="Open" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the way selecting an item works, you could pass the current item as a command parameter to the command if you set the `ContextMenu` property of each individual `DataRow`:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecordsForList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="xcdg:DataRow">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=xcdg:DataGridControl}}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" Header="Open" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

The other option would be to write some code in the view that actually selects an item on right-click, e.g.:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecordsForList}}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Header="Open" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="xcdg:DataRow">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="xgrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

---

```
private void xgrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataRow row = sender as Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataRow;
    xgrid.CurrentItem = row.DataContext;
}
```